# How to add up specific parts of a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list with a bunch of data in the format of: `date, month, data`

I would like all of the entries with the same date to sum up all of their data and the output be simply date, data.  In other words, the data looks something like this

```
[(1/1/2011, August, 5), (1/1/2011, July, 4), (1,1,2011, June, 1), (1/6/2011, December, 5)]
```

For this example I would want the output to be like this:

```
[(1/1/2011, 10), (1/6/2011, 5)]
```

How would I go about doing this?  I know this would involve a for loop and if a date is similar it would sum up the data.  But I'm stumped on how to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary to keep the unique dates:

```
dates = {}
for (date, month, day) in your_list:
    if date not in dates:
        dates[date] = day
    else
        dates[date] += day
```

You'd then have to go back to a list if you wanted the output as you've specified:

```
outlist = []
for (date, daycount) in dates.items():
    outlist.append( (date, daycount) )
```

That being said, whenever you're using dates, it's usually useful to store them as datetime objects and then operations like adding dates are more straightforward.

Comment: In that first loop, you could also use `dates = collections.defaultdict(int)` and then just `dates[date] += day`, instead of the `if-else`

Comment: How'd I never know about this?

Comment: For the second block of code, maybe `outlist = list(dates.items())` for Python 3.X or `outlist = dates.items()` for Python 2.X?

Comment: You could also get rid of the ``if-else`` sentence through the ``dict.get()`` method by setting a default value to ``0``.
``dates[date] = day + dates.get(date, 0)``

Comment: These are good suggestions, but I'm going to keep the answer as is so that OP can try the if/else way, then make it more succinct with these more advanced concepts.  Then he/she can come to comments and implement these nice tips

Comment: @AdamHughes - exactly why I mention it :). So many things I've stumbled across in SO answers/comments that now I couldn't live without, so I'm always happy to pass along! Might be overkill/mismatch for this case, but another convenience class I like is `collections.Counter()`

Answer (score 1):

Find all the dates in the list and then you can count each one:

```
dates = [('1/1/2011', 'August', 5), ('1/1/2011', 'July', 4),
         ('1/1/2011', 'June', 1), ('1/6/2011', 'December', 5)]

each_date = set(d[0] for d in dates)

count_dates = [(d, sum(i[2] for i in dates if i[0] == d)) for d in each_date]

print(count_dates)
# -> [('1/6/2011', 5), ('1/1/2011', 10)]
```

Comment: Your input is different.

Comment: @RahulKP The given input doesn't parse

Comment: @JaredGoguen check the input with question and the answer.

Comment: @RahulKP it should still work regardless of the way the dates are formatted (unless it's a datetime object with date and time data, that is). As filifunk has it, the list will give back a NameError, and trying to assign a variable named 1/1/2011 would give a SyntaxError since / is an operator.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner based on [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> dates = [('1/1/2011', 'August', 5), ('1/1/2011', 'July', 4), 
             ('1/1/2011', 'June', 1), ('1/6/2011', 'December', 5)]
>>> [(date, sum(map(itemgetter(-1), group))) for (date, group) in groupby(dates, key=itemgetter(0))]
[('1/1/2011', 10), ('1/6/2011', 5)]
```

Notice that for this demo I used the same `dates` as in @alecrasmussen's answer as the data provided by the OP cannot be interpreted by Python.